# Sample size equation for multi-class distribution

Tags: multiclass-classification, sampling

I have a large (`k>15`) number of potential classes involved in a text classification problem, and don't know the true distribution of these classes in the prediction set. Moreover, I currently do not know any of the **true** labels.

The plan is to manually tag a random subset of the N data points (`N>200,000`) to approximate the true distribution, but I am unsure how to determine the number of points (`n<N`) that need to be tagged.

Cochran’s Sample Size Formula allows calculation of a recommended sample size, given a desired level of precision, desired confidence level, and the estimated proportion of the attribute present in the population. However, I am unsure whether this is only meant for a binary classification (as are the examples I have read), and/or how to extend it to fit my situation.

Can anyone refer me to an example of calculating sample size to determine a multi-class distribution? The method need not be Cochran's.

Comment: check here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4071155/

Comment: and here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/what-is-a-good-sample-size?rq=1